# 50 seconds to get my response from heroku rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

Almost 2 years ago I wrote web application and deployed it on heroku. Since, I've just maintained it a bit so I am not very up-to-date with Rails.

I have serious production problems I need to solve asap. It's a restful API.

```
 curl  http://myserver.com/users/1
```

take 50 sec now. It's not cached. However :

```
 curl  http://myserver.com/users
```

take 100 ms, it's cached.

Maybe a DB access problem ? Nop ! I did:

```
> app.get 'users/1'
```

I got a response in 60 ms.

Maybe a rendering problem ? Nop, I rewrite a controller method like this:

```
 def show
    render json: 'foo'
 end
```

It was the same, it took 50 seconds to got response : `'foo'` Then, I plugged NewRelic plugin: no latence has been spotted.

My only log is:

`2014-07-12T17:04:44.650173+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/1" host=www.-----.net request_id=323db6cf-73c0-459f-928a-dd88e1229779 fwd="89.156.00.00" dyno=web.1 connect=1 service=182 status=200 bytes=342` (got before getting response in client :/)

I don't ask for solution. I'm asking about: what/where can I investigate ?

Comment: what does the network tab of chrome/firefox developer tools tell you? it should point out the component that is taking so long to respond

Comment: It so weird: I got a 200 code then I'm waiting for the repsonse, here the timing: Blocking: 0.9 ms Sending: 0.1 ms Waiting: 92 ms Receiving: 59 sec. (it's always 59 sec)

Comment: Possibly related to my [post here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24717495/slow-page-load-on-heroku)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found information on Twitter since I had the same issue.

this seems to be related to websockets.  Disabling it seems to cure the issues.

```
heroku labs:disable websockets -a myapp -p production
```

this makes it work as it used to, though the logs now look different :)

thanks to @dwaynemac @stephane_tavera on twitter.

**EDIT**:

Heroku shows this as a resolve issue, but answer applies in case it happens again.

https://status.heroku.com/incidents/649#update-2163

Comment: Yep, it seems fixed ! Thank you for sharing info

Answer (score 1):

it is only after the server hasn't been hit in a while?  Heroku will spin down the servers if they are not in use and it takes a while for them to spin up.